# Semi-complex Shipping Rule

Tags: 7, commerce

I don't know anything about how rules work so I'm looking for help from the hive mind.
I need to set up shipping based on these calculations but not sure where to start.

Originally I was looking for rules to do all of this:

`If product category is silencer & size is large shipping is $10 per that type of line item
If product category is silencer & size is small shipping is $7 per that type of line item
If product category is silencer & at least 5 line items are strike type of center shipping is free on all silencers
If product category is sbr or sbs shipping is $15 per that type of line item
If product category is accessories and no other items are in cart shipping is $10 flat rate
If accessories are added to orders with any other types of line items no additional shipping should be added to order`

I've now broken out accessories as a different product type, and added the "Commerce Shipping Field" module. So that takes care of the first 2 lines, as well as the SBR and SBS shipping.

I still need the 3rd line to work.

Also, I set up flat rate shipping for accessories and it works for orders with only accessories in them, but if you add any other product the shipping method provided is not reliable, sometimes flat rate is chosen, sometimes the commerce shipping rate is chosen. I think it has to do with the order the products are added to the cart.

I really need some help on this. And talk to me like I'm not quite ready for the 'Drupal for Dummies' series. I can create sites well enough, but I've never had to deal with Rules before and they're kicking my ass!

Comment: Could really use some help with this!

Comment: "least 5 line items are strike type of center" is that a product or a line item type?

Comment: it's a vocabulary term, but I could make it a separate type of product if that would make things easier.